# I want call a function that is on a script that sits on multiple GameObjects. But I want the function to activate only one Object at that instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a simple recipe board for a cooking game. There will be 4 buttons(Game Objects) for available recipes. Each Game Object holds the common script that will change the recipe based on either the recipe being correctly satisfied

The script sets references to the children (text) on the button that represent the recipe name, ingredients etc.

```
[SerializeField]
private Text RecipePanelName;

[SerializeField]
private Text RecipePanelIngredient1;

[SerializeField]
private Text RecipePanelIngredient2;

[SerializeField]
private Text RecipePanelIngredient3;

[SerializeField]
private Text RecipePanelPrice;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject RPIng1;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject RPIng2;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject RPIng3;

private int x = 0;
public REcipeClass[] RECIPES;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    RECIPES = Crops_and_Recipes.getInstance().RECIPES;

    ChangeRecipe();

}

public void ChangeRecipe()
{
    x = Random.Range(0, RECIPES.Length);

    Debug.Log("REcipe lenght is " + RECIPES.Length);
    Debug.Log("index number is " + x);

    RecipePanelName.text = RECIPES[x].NAME.ToString();

    RPIng2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = RPIng1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale;
    RPIng3.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = RPIng1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale;


    if (RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS.Length == 1)
    {
        RecipePanelIngredient1.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[0].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
        RPIng2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        RPIng3.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS.Length == 2)
    {
        RecipePanelIngredient1.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[0].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
        RecipePanelIngredient2.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[1].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
        RPIng3.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS.Length == 3)
    {
        RecipePanelIngredient1.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[0].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
        RecipePanelIngredient2.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[1].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
        RecipePanelIngredient3.text = RECIPES[x].INGREDIENTS[2].CROP_TYPE.ToString();
    }

    RecipePanelPrice.text = RECIPES[x].PRICE.ToString();
}
```

But since this script sits on all 4 recipe buttons, if i call for a *ChangeRecipe()* function from anywhere else, it will change all the recipes which will ultimately disrupt the gameplay experience.

How do i make it so that the function changes the recipe on only the button that was clicked?

Comment: Use command pattern. Create a class for each button inheriting some common interface (IButton) with ChangeRecipe() method. In every button class inject the recipe for that button through constructor. On button click call IButton.ChangeRecipe().

Comment: Hi! @DeepakMishra Thank you for the suggestion. I'm a bit of a newbie at this and am trying to figure out how the command pattern thing works. Can you maybe also suggest some resources I could refer for this ? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in